# In html background image disappears in input, when I insert p or span under it

Tags: html, css, input, background-image

Here are two `<input>` fields with `background-image` inside it, the looks normal. When I add two `<p>` or `<span>` after first `input` and before second (middle of them) everything is OK, but if I add one `<p>` tag middle of them and one after second input or before first input, then `background-image` disappears accordingly on second or first input field.

Can someone explain what's happening?

```css
form {
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input:first-child {
  background-image: url(./Images/user-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input:last-child {
  background-image: url(./Images/lock-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
      <p>text</p>
      <input type="password" name="" id="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </form>
```

I tried display:flex, display:block - same here.

Comment: Let me ask you, what do you think `:last-child` does?

Comment: BTW, a more robust approach would be to use CSS `class` names - or attribute selectors, e.g. `form input[type=text], form input[type=password] { background-image: url(...); }`.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a p element after the second input that input is no longer the last-child.

You can get round that in this instance by using last-of-type instead:

```css
form {
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input:first-of-type {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input:last-of-type {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  <p>text</p>
  <input type="password" name="" id="" />
  <p>text</p>
</form>
```

Likewise you could use first-of-type for the first input to cover the case when there is a p element before that.